# Как сравнить большое количество списков между собой?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Нужно создать больше 300000 ArrayList, заполненных случайными числами,   и найти одинаковые среди них. Что лучше использовать: hashmap, arraylist, что-то другое?

Upd. Arraylist вида {a,b,c} :abc случайны. И таких >300000.  Сравнивать "на лету" каждый новый с существующими.

Comment: массив обычный не подходит?

Comment: стойте, вы же полностью поменяли задание

Comment: Я потому и обновил вопрос, что увидел: он не точен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам подойдет `ArrayList`. Для нахождения подходящей структуры можно использовать такую картинку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображенияwd wd]

А если заранее известно количество данных в списке, то подойдет обычный массив. Потому что он быстрее чем `ArrayList`

P.S. Вы изменили вопрос. ArrayList или массив все равно подходят лучше всего.  Вы можете отсортировать массив методом `Arrays.sort` и сравнить друг с другом `Arrays.equals`.

Comment: По сути мне нужно будет сравнивать коллекцию с arraylist. Т.к. каждое новое значение нужно для хранения добавлять в какую-то коллекцию.